# lldb-server inherits environment from client, not from host

Tags: debugging, lldb

I am trying to launch a process for remote debugging using lldb-serve. I want the process to run with environment from the remote machine where lldb-server is running.

The target.inherit-env does not work as I expected from reading the documentation.

If I tell inherit env the process runs with env from **client** rather than env from remote target.
If I set inherit env to false the process runs with absolutely empty env.

Target is linux, I tried both linux and windows as client

How do I force the launched process to inherit env from **lldb-server** process?